# Error AADSTS65001 when trying to login with Azure AD

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-mobile-services, azure-active-directory

I followed the example from the link below.
I followed each step but at the end. I got the annoying error:
"AADST65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with id... etc".

https://blog.xamarin.com/authenticate-xamarin-mobile-apps-using-azure-active-directory/

Any idea of what I did was wrong during the setup based on the link? Am I missing something?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have any experience with Xamarin, but from what I do know about Azure AD this message shows up when you've requested a permission in your AAD app configuration which requires a tenant administrator to consent (e.g. to approve). Your options at this point are to either have your tenant admin log into your app to consent (this is a one-time thing) or change your selected permissions so that you no longer require admin consent.

As far as the blog post, normally following those steps wouldn't require admin consent. Is it possible that you requested additional permissions besides "Allow sign-on" and "Read directory data"?